# Unable to join scattered text in a single row

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, web-scraping, data-cleaning

I've found a script in some post in SO where it has been used to scrape and organize a scattered piece of text in a single-line. However, instead of making my script a single liner I wanted to break it in few lines to make it more readable and understandable. With my new try, the output I'm having is somewhat messy. I'm almost there, though! Any help to produce the output in a single row with no redundant space in between will be appreciated.

This is the html elements:

```
html_elem="""
<div class="post-detail">
    <p>11525 23 RDX</p>


    <p>HAMILTON,
    AB
    ,
    S4K 2N9

    ,
    ROYAL STREET
    </p>

    <p><a rel="nofollow" href="mailto:tahir20790@yahoo.com">tahir20790@yahoo.com</a></p>
    <p><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.fake_one.org" target="_blank">So You Are Here</a></p>
</div>
"""
```

The type of solution I'm expecting is more like (not a single liner solution which is already there in that post):

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

tree = fromstring(html_elem)
for item in tree.cssselect(".post-detail p"):
    if item.text:
        print(' '.join(item.text.split()))
```

Output I'm having:

```
11525 23 RDX
HAMILTON, AB , S4K 2N9 , ROYAL STREET
```

What I would like to have:

```
11525 23 RDX HAMILTON, AB , S4K 2N9 , ROYAL STREET
```

Btw, this was the one liner solution:

```
print(' '.join([' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in tree.cssselect(".post-detail p") if item.text]))
```

Comment: Try: `print(' '.join(item.text.replace('\n', ' ').split()))`

Comment: Thanks  cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, for your solution but it gives the same output as I'm having with my existing script.

Answer (score 0):

You print each `item` (`<p>...</p>`) by itself. *Accumulate* them in a list then print.

```
s = []
for item in tree.cssselect(".post-detail p"):
    if item.text:
        s.append(' '.join(item.text.split()))
print(' '.join(s))
```

If you want to avoid printing some items/elements, test them before adding them to the list.

Comment: Ain't it possible to get the desired result without using list comprehension cause the one liner solution looks more appealing. Thanks.

Comment: Added the solution given in a single line.\ but that is not what i expect.

Comment: I guess i'm just not obsessed with one-liners or *looks*.  Besides you specifically asked for a something other than a *one-liner* - `...not a single liner solution ...`